# Error in GROUP BY Apache Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, group-by, hive

I have a table ratings containing:

```
userid INT
movieid INT
rating FLOAT
timestmp STRING

select movieid, ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as Rating, COUNT(userid) as rtn_crt, ROUND(((Rating*rtn_cnt)+(100*3.5))/(rtn_cnt+100),1) as w_rating
from ratings 
GROUP BY movieid 
LIMIT 50;
```

The error message:

> `org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException`: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: `SemanticException` [Error 10025]: Line 2:6 Expression not in GROUP BY key `rtn_cnt`

I tried using the function CAST but still not working, and receive the same error

```
select movieid, CAST(AVG(rating) AS FLOAT) as Rating, COUNT(userid) as rtn_crt,
CAST((Rating*rtn_cnt) AS FLOAT) + CAST((100*$AVG_MEAN) AS FLOAT)
       /CAST((rtn_cnt+100) AS FLOAT) as w_rating
from ratings 
GROUP BY movieid 
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should recommend you to rewrite your SQL-query using subquery like this:

```
SELECT t.*, ROUND(((t.Rating*t.rtn_cnt)+(100*3.5))/(t.rtn_cnt+100),1) as w_rating 
FROM (
    SELECT movieid, ROUND(AVG(rating), 1) as Rating, COUNT(userid) as rtn_crt
    FROM ratings 
    GROUP BY movieid 
    LIMIT 50
) t;
```